# Failed when render HTML content with Laravel HTML helper

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm a newbie of Laravel. When I made the layout for my app, I want to display html content when use Laravel's HTML helper. Example `{{ HTML::link('#','User <b class="caret"></b>'); }}`
 but it was render as

```
Login <b class="caret"></b>
```

.

How I can display HTML content with Laravel's HTML helper. Please help me!!!

Comment: You cant. It automatically escapes the output. You'll need to just write raw html for that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this is your desired output since you did not indicate it.

But anyway

`{{ HTML::link('#','User', array('class' => 'caret')) }}`

Basically these are the parameters accepted by `HTML::link()`

`{{ HTML::link(url, title, [attributes as an array], secure)}}`

See the [API](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/) for further info